# getting java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry during packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex issue when try to add opentok library

Tags: java, android, apache, build.gradle, opentok

I am trying to configure audio/video chat and archive audio/video chat with OpenTok API. I have successfully configure audio/video chat with OpenTok but unable to perform archive.

Getting following issue:

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.**

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack.class

This is my library:

[image]

This is my log:
[image]
[image]

Following are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    //compile project(':androidConferenceWebRTC')
    compile project(':countryPicker')
    compile project(':customEmoji')
    compile project(':sugar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.3.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.5'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.3'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.2'
    compile 'com.splitwise:tokenautocomplete:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
    //compile files('libs/opentok-android-sdk.jar')
    compile 'com.tokbox:opentok-server-sdk:2.3.2'
    //compile files('libs/opentok-server-sdk-2.3.2-javadoc.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using the java-server-sdk from an Android application (client). Android is not a supported target for that project.

The target is not supported because this is a bad practice and it can pose a security risk. Using this package on the client means that your application code would have the API Secret in a String in your code, and that means a malicious user could decompile and decode that value. You should instead create sessions, tokens, and start archives from a server. You server is free to implement any type of authentication or authorization that you find appropriate.